# Can't add BorderSides to NetworkImage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, border

Feels like I'm missing something obvious, but this code creates a lovely border around my image:

```
Widget buildImageWithBorder(String imageUrl) {
  return Container(
    height: 240.0,
    width: 222.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 4.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

and setting the border to use four `BorderSide`s also works:

```
border: Border(
    left: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 4.0,
    ),
    right: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 4.0,
    ),
    bottom: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 4.0,
    ),
    top: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      width: 4.0,
    ),
  ),
```

but if I remove any of the `BorderSide`s (the one I'd like to remove entirely is `top`), or change the width of a `BorderSide` to `0.0` (i.e. only have 3 Borders), no borders show up. How can I get three borders (with border radius)?

Comment: Cant you set the border color to clear on the top side?

Comment: This sounded like a great idea. I tried it, but if any of the BorderSides are different (e.g. I change the width, or the color, of one of them), the entire border just disappears.